# SSRS reporting in SharePoint Online

Tags: office-365, reporting-services

Can we Create SSRS Reports in SharePoint Online?

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/239208

This article states that we cannot, but the information is old, What's the latest on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. Please check following link with all available features in SharePoint online https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx

I think that the best option to build reports is Excel Services or Power BI.

Answer (score 3):

Yep,

You can use ThorApps BI Service to host your ssrs reports in SharePoint Online. 
Its available from the Sharepoint App Store or from https://www.thorapps.com

Adrian

Answer (score -1):

There are third party SharePoint Add-Ins that make this possible. I've described how to set up one such free to use add-in in this blog post:

[Display SQL Server Reporting Services Reports in SharePoint Online](http://www.axioworks.com/2018/08/display-sql-server-reporting-services-reports-in-sharepoint-online/)

It's fairly straight forward to set up. Install and register the add-in in SharePont Online, drop the add-in on a SharePoint page and then provide a url and credentials to connect to your SSRS server in the cloud and finally select the report you want to render.

Comment: Welcome Paul, may you please double check the link you posted, to ensure it is in fact relevant to the question.

Comment: Opps. Sorry have updated now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That's a great article. I am going to give it a try. Just a heads up in case someone else flags it but you should disclose your affiliation :)